# What are the celestial creatures the Conjure Celestial spell can summon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Looking at the list of monsters, it seems that the Conjure Celestial spell really only act on three possible creatures:

- Pegasus (CR 2)
- Couatl (CR 4)
- Unicorn (CR 5—requires spell slot 9)

Am I missing something? It seems very restrained for a spell level 7 to only be able to conjure 3 creatures...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep, you've found them all.

As far as this spell lacking versatility is concerned, remember that versatility is not the only measure of power. ([Power is power](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0657.html).) For example, the 6th-level spell *Planar Ally* can summon pretty much *anything*, but the caster has no control over it whatsoever. Going outside of the Cleric spell list, the 7th-level spells *Mordenkainen's Sword* or *Finger of Death* are both entirely without versatility.

*Conjure Celestial*, on the other hand, is reliable and controllable. As far as versatility is concerned, one of the creatures you can summon is the Couatl. The Couatl has 14 different spells, almost all of which it can use multiple times per day. It can also use its *Change Shape* ability to turn into a bunch of other things. In fact, the Couatl is so ridiculously versatile that I'd argue that it inherently makes *Conjure Celestial* a well and truly versatile spell.

Comment: Keep in mind that the DM has control over 'Conjure' spells such as Conjure Celestial as per the Compendium : https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/SA_Compendium_1.03.pdf  at the top of page 7.  The player can certainly express a wish for a Couatl to appear, but it hinges on the whim of the DM granting such a request.  I don't know if that level of randomness changes your opinion or not, but thought I'd include it here.

Comment: @Airatome Ah crap, I forgot about that. Conjure Celestial still grants control where Planar Ally doesn't, so it's not a total loss...I'll have to think about how to edit that.

Comment: @Airatome, interesting... I thought it would be the caster's choice. But re-reading the *Conjure Celestial* spell, it indeed does not actually say. It does not even give the caster the choice of CR. Ouch!

Comment: @AlexisWilke I don't know anyone who actually runs it that way, because everyone I've talked to agrees that it's dumb.

Comment: @Miniman, I would most certainly let my players choose, but it is interesting to see that the rules say otherwise...

Comment: @Miniman Fortunately; I only included this as a RAW link, and not what we interpret as 'dumb' .  For what it's worth, while I agree with you both that handing control over such a spell (Conjure Woodland / Fey have even more possibilities than Celestial) with so many various choices to the DM is dumb; I could also see why the intended rules on this spell make the DM choose.  To prevent things that do not fit into the game world of the DM's creation from being summoned forth and/or potentially abused.  If you are opening a conjuration portal, who knows what might come out!

Comment: @Airatome I dunno, I sometimes think it was actually a stealth nerf to prevent pixie abuse.

Comment: @Miniman Have there been any expansions to the list in the past 3 years?

Comment: @ETgothome Yes. One in the Volo's Guide to Monsters: the Ki-rin. (CR 12)

Comment: @AlexisWilke That's not an expansion to the list, since the spell maxes out at CR 5.

Answer (score 6):

There have been several more released since this question was originally asked.

#### *Monster Manual*

- [Couatl](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/couatl) (CR 4)
- [Pegasus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pegasus) (CR 2)
- [Unicorn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/unicorn) (CR 5)

#### *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*

- [Battleforce Angel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/battleforce-angel) (CR 5)
- [Felidar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/felidar) (CR 5)

#### *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*

- [Hollyphant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hollyphant) (CR 5)

#### *Mythic Odysseys of Theros*

- [Winged Bull](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/winged-bull) (CR 4)
- [Winged Lion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/winged-lion) (CR 4)

Comment: Teamwork FTW! 

Comment: There is one more now. Starlight Apparition, CR 5, introduced in Boo's Astral Menagerie.

Comment: Although, it might be unhelpful to include Starlight Apparition on this list because its Astral Existence would make it disappear as soon as you finish conjuring it (if you're outside the astral plane).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the easiest way to obtain such a list is using a website like D&D Beyond. You can select filters to choose up to max of CR5 and list celestials: https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=3&filter-cr-max=9

As of December 17, 2023, this search yields 19 creatures and one swarm (Swarm of Sunflies):

- Sunfly (CR 0)
- Dabus, Lantern Archon, Musteval Guardinal, Pegasus, Star Lancer (CR 2)
- Bariaur Wanderer, Living Portent (CR 3)
- Couatl, Hound Archon, Winged Bull, Winged Lion (CR 4)
- Battleforce Angel, Felidar, Hollyphant, Mercane, Rain, Starlight Apparition, Unicorn (CR 5)

Winged Bull and Winged Lion from the *Mythic Odysseys of Theros* might also provide the DM some ideas for creating new celestials from animals.